# How can I get the inner exception message from a RESTful response in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, rest, exception, testing

There is a request which fails and the error message says

```
Response (Uri: (null), Code: 0, Content: (null), Error: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.)
```

The code to execute the request is as follows:

```
protected RestResponse Execute(RestRequest request)
{
    var response = client.ExecuteAsync(request).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
    {
        return response;
    }
    if (response.StatusCode < HttpStatusCode.OK || response.StatusCode >= HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
    {
        throw new RestException($"[Rest] Calling {response.ResponseUri} an error occured: {response.StatusCode} - {response.Content}");
    }

    return response;
}
```

I'm trying to get that inner exception message but I don't know how to catch that exception from a RESTful response.

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
if (response.StatusCode < HttpStatusCode.OK || response.StatusCode >= HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
{
    Console.Write("Inner Exception: " + response.ErrorException.Message);
    throw new RestException($"[Rest] Calling {response.ResponseUri} an error occured: {response.StatusCode} - {response.Content}");
}
```

I get the same message: "*Inner Exception: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.*"

Comment: There's no such thing as a "restful" response. You can only get what the *server* sends. There's a standard problem details response specified in [RFC 9457](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc9457). What you posted though is just the `Message` part of a .NET exception, not any server response. Where does your code use `Exception.Message` instead of `Exception.ToString()` ?

Comment: In the code you posted, `Console.Write("Inner Exception: " + response.ErrorException.Message);` only extracts the message part of the exception. Write the entire exception text instead. That will include all inner exceptions and the stack trace.`Console.WriteLine("Inner Exception: {0}",response.ErrorException);`. Even better use proper logging instead of writing to the console.

Comment: In any case an SSL exception means the connection failed either because the wrong TLS version was used or an invalid certificate.

Comment: Thank yo very much. Even though, I wanted to get the inner message and now I got it.

Answer (score 0):

As the user @PanagiotisKanavos pointed in a comment:

> There's no such thing as a "restful" response. You can only get what
> the server sends. There's a standard problem details response
> specified in [RFC 9457](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc9457). What you posted though is just the
> `Message` part of a .NET exception, not any server response. (...)
> In the code you posted, `Console.Write("Inner Exception: " + response.ErrorException.Message);` only extracts the message part of
> the exception. Write the entire exception text instead. That will
> include all inner exceptions and the stack trace.
> `Console.WriteLine("Inner Exception: {0}",response.ErrorException);`.
> Even better use proper logging instead of writing to the console.

I did as he said a I found what I was lookig for.